PDF not recognized as PDF when opened in _self
In my Blazor project, I utilize JavaScript for managing file downloads and displaying PDFs. I transfer a BLOB via interop to JavaScript and subsequently open the browser's PDF viewer. This process functions properly on Firefox, but encounters issues on Chromium based browsers. While the PDF is displayed correctly, Chromium PDF-Viewer's download button identifies the file as "AllFiles" when opened in _self, and only recognizes it as a PDF when opened in _blank.
I have been unable to resolve these issues, and I'm perplexed by the discrepancy in how the same BLOB is perceived as a PDF or not based on whether it's opened in _self or _blank.
Does anyone have insights on how to make _self opening work properly?
//contentType = 'application/pdf'
async function handleFile(filename, contentType, data) {
    var sUserAg = navigator.userAgent;
    const file = new File([data], filename, { type: contentType });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const anchorElement = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(anchorElement);
    anchorElement.href = url;
    anchorElement.target = "_self";
    anchorElement.click();
    if (sUserAg.indexOf("Firefox") <= -1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }, 600000);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }, 100);
    }
    anchorElement.remove();
}


Try adding a filename hint? anchorElement.setAttribute("download",filename)

Thank you for your response. While the proposed solution ensures direct downloading of the file with the correct filename, my concern is facilitating users to download the PDF from the browser's PDF viewer after opening the Blob in the same tab.

Ah right didn't understand that.
